# Session Beans for Entity Class Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, session, netbeans

I follow [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html) tutorial and I am told to create a Session Beans for Entity Classes.
The instructions are as follow :

*1. Press Ctrl-N (⌘-N on Mac) to open the File wizard.*

*2. Select the Persistence category, then select Session Beans for Entity Classes.*

But in my version of Netbeans (8.2) there is no "Session Beans for Entity Classes".
Instead, different from the turorial, I have "DB scripts for Entity classes".

Is it in a different folder ? Do I have to install it separately ?

Comment: Are you using the correct NetBeans? My install (JavaEE) has all the correct choices in the Persistence folder, including Session Beans for Entity Classes

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, it was because i was not using a web application, if you create a maven web application and you look for session beans for entity classes you'll find it. (Maybe your project weren't a web aplication)

Comment: I am creating a Maven web application and getting the same error. Netbeans 12.6

Answer (score 0):

You choose New / Other. Then search "session" in filter, then choose "Session Beans for Entity Classes"